# DevExtreme Form, how to submit data to controller in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devextreme

I have a simple form as below:

```
   == test.cshtml ==
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @(Html.DevExtreme().Form<Models.Tenant.Data>()
    .ID("form")
    .ColCount(2)
    .Items(items => {
        items.AddSimpleFor(m => m.code)
            .Editor(e => e
                .TextBox().MaxLength(5)
            ).ValidationRules(r => r
                .AddRequired()
                .Message("Code is required")
            ).DataField("code");
            

        items.AddSimpleFor(m => m.name)
            .Editor(e => e
                .TextBox().MaxLength(256)
            ).ValidationRules(r => r
                .AddRequired()
                .Message("Name is required")
            ).DataField("name");

        items.AddSimpleFor(m => m.email).Editor(e => e
               .TextBox().MaxLength(256)).DataField("email");

        items.AddSimpleFor(m => m.active).DataField("active");
    })
    .OnContentReady(@<text>
        function(e) {
            e.component.validate();
        }
    </text>)
    .FormData(Model)
)
```

I also have prepared a controller as below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(FormDataCollection form)
    {

        return Created("", newTenant);
    }
```

But I didn't find the way on how to call controller within the DevExtreme Form?

anybody can help me, please?

many thanks in advance

Don

Answer (score 1):

First you must add a button to the form, like so:

```
items.AddButton()
     .HorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.Left)
     .ButtonOptions(b => b.Text("Register")
                          .Type(ButtonType.Success)
                          .UseSubmitBehavior(true)
     );
```

Now take in mind the `UseSubmitBehaviour(true)` this means when you click it the form will submit. Well this mean you must encapsulate this component in a `@using (Html.BeginForm()){}`.

Example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // Your DevExtreme Form component here
}
```

Your controller action will receive the forms model, so it should be:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Insert(Models.Tenant.Data data)
{
    return Created("", newTenant);
}
```